# How to detect text selection events in a SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, mobile

I'm wondering how I can detect the text selection events of the user. Specifically, I want to be able to retrieve the selected text when the user selects some text and learn how to handle this event.

I've seen a few code examples, but none of them seem to work correctly. What's the best way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

I've seen codes that creates a Text view and add onTap method. I don't want to do that. I want to use Apple's selection and when selection is made and few milliseconds passed, i wanna show contextMenu.

Comment: Only possible with UIKit right now

Comment: how is it possible?

Comment: The delegate has methods for selection https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitextfielddelegate